# Nginx reverse proxy to multiple tomcat containers

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, tomcat

I am trying to setup Nginx reverse proxy for tomcat application docker containers. I have app1 and app2 listening on host port 8028 and 8030( inside containers bind on 8080). and Nginx and docker setup is on different servers.

192.168.1.10 => nginx => example.com

192.168.1.20:8028/app1 => tomcat app1 (doker container)

192.168.1.20:8030/app2 => tomcat app2 (doker container)

and now trying to set up a proxy to access the app as

1. https://example.com/app1 => proxy to 192.168.1.20:8028/app1
2. https://example.com/app1 => proxy to 192.168.1.20:8030/app2

Now the problem is tomcat redirectPort is set to "443". and which is creating redirection loops. If I access the same tomcat app with apache and ajp connector it is accessible. but there are multiple applications and want to set up a central proxy server.

Below is the configuration

```
upstream backend1 {
    server 192.168.1.20:8028;

   }

upstream backend2 {
    server 192.168.1.20:8030;

   }



server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-access.log ;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log ;

        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    large_client_header_buffers 4 256k;

    location /app1 {

        proxy_pass                    http://backend1/app1;
    }
    location /app2 {

         proxy_pass                     http://backend2/app2;
    }
    #return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}


server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 256k;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-access.log ;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log ;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/conf/ssl/ca.crt;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf/ssl/apache.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf/ssl/apache.key;


        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    location /app1 {

        proxy_pass                    http://backend1/app1;
    }
    location /app2 {

         proxy_pass                     http://backend2/app2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to fix the redirection loop issue by adding header proxy_set_header X-SSL-Request 1;

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix this redirection loop using below header in location block.

```
proxy_set_header X-SSL-Request 1;
```